# How to Make a materialize CSS button's width same as col s12?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I want to make the Submit button's length same as the input field above it.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="speciality" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="speciality">Speciality</label>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Search
        <i class="material-icons right">search</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: `width:100%` doesn't work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your column which you have your input field in is limited to a certain width (in the way how the Bootstrap columns work), you can put the `.btn` inside a column as well.

After that, you can use the following CSS to make the width equal to the input field:

```
.col.s12 > .btn {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Of course if the `button` as an element does not bend to this CSS-rule, you can use `<a class="btn">` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Surround the button with a div with `col s12` classes and add `btn-block` to the button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Search
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
.btn-block {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I would add that one needs to be mindful of nested rows when applying this technique.